# How To Train Regression Model With multiple 3D Array?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, deep-learning, scikit-image

I want to train my regression model with 3D array? how can I do it in Python? can you please guide me. Actually I want to predict regression value from giving input of multiple 3D arrays. Is it possible to predict just single float number from multiple 3d arrays?. Thanks

train.model((x1,x2,x3..xN), y-value).

where x1,x2,..xN are 3D array.
and Y is output just single float number.

Comment: r u using raw python or with some libraries such as tensorflow, pytorch

Comment: is the `N` fixed? a ML model should take a fixed input shape

Comment: thanks for comment, Yes actually I am using python libraries which you mentioned. and  N is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is to reshape your 3D samples to flat 1D samples. The following example code uses `tf.reshape` to reshape input before feeding to a regular dense network for regression to a single value output by `tf.identity` (no activation).

```py
%tensorflow_version 2.x
%reset -f

import tensorflow as tf
from   tensorflow.keras import *
from   tensorflow.keras.models import *
from   tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from   tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *

class regression_model(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(regression_model,self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = Dense(units=300, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)
        self.dense2 = Dense(units=200, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)
        self.dense3 = Dense(units=1,   activation=tf.identity)

    @tf.function
    def call(self,x):
        h1 = self.dense1(x)
        h2 = self.dense2(h1)
        u  = self.dense3(h2) # Output
        return u

if __name__=="__main__":
    inp = [[[1],[2],[3],[4]], [[3],[3],[3],[3]]] # 2 samples of whatever shape
    exp = [[10],              [12]] # Regress to sums for example'

    inp = tf.constant(inp,dtype=tf.float32)
    exp = tf.constant(exp,dtype=tf.float32)

    NUM_SAMPLES = 2
    NUM_VALUES_IN_1SAMPLE = 4
    inp = tf.reshape(inp,(NUM_SAMPLES,NUM_VALUES_IN_1SAMPLE))

    model = regression_model()
    model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(1e-3))
    
    model.fit(x=inp,y=exp, batch_size=len(inp), epochs=100)

    print(f"\nPrediction from {inp}, will be:")
    print(model.predict(x=inp, batch_size=len(inp), steps=1))
# EOF
```

Comment: Thank you for comment and given me a way to do. I was also thinking to convert 3d array to 1d to train model. But I was confused that may be there is way to train model with actual 3d arrays. and second important thing i want to ask from you , can we give any range for our output value (Y). eg: 0 to 200 . It means predicted value should come under this range.? thanks alot

Comment: you mean I reshape 3d arrays to 1D like this?

eg: train.model((x1,x2,x3..xN), y-value)
where x1, x2,x3..xN are 1D arrays.

or 
i convert all 3d arrays into 1d arrays and put into one single array like this.
abc = x1,x2,x3..xN
train.model(abc, y-value)

Comment: yes, x1 3D --> x1 1D, with the same number of numeric values

Comment: at least in tensorflow you can't use 3D directly with Dense layer, you have to flatten every sample first; and basically, 3D or 1D doesn't reduce the effectiveness of the network

Comment: this Conv3D layer works with 3d input: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3D